# Finding the largest 16:9 rectangle within another rectangle

Tags: lua, rectangles

I am working on this Lua script and I need to be able to find the largest 16:9 rectangle within another rectangle that doesn't have a specific aspect ratio. So can you tell me how I can do that? You don't have to write Lua - pseudocode works too.

Thanks!

This I have tried and can confirm that won't work on lower ratio outer rects.

```
if wOut > hOut then 
wIn = wOut
hIn = (wIn / 16) *9
else 
hIn = hOut
wIn = (hIn / 9) * 16 
end
```

Comment: Have you tried solving it at all - even the pseudo code stage? If not, you really should attempt to solve it for yourself first. If so, include what you've got so far in the question.

Comment: Here is what I have tried and I can say that it wont work on 4:3 outer rectangles.

Comment: Damnit, cant write multiple lines

Comment: @Funstein Edit the question to include additional information, don't just put it in comments.

Comment: if wOut > hOut then wIn = wOut; hIn = (wIn / 16) *9; else hIn = hOut; wIn = (hIn / 9) * 16 end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
heightCount = originalHeight / 9;
widthCount = originalWidth / 16;

if (heightCount == 0 || widthCount == 0)
    throw "No 16/9 rectangle";

recCount = min(heightCount, widthCount);

targetHeight = recCount * 9;
targetWidth = recCount * 16;
```

So far, any rectangle with left = 0..(originalWidth - targetWidth) and top = 0..(originalHeight - targetHeight) and width = targetWidth and height = targetHeight should satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Thanks! Why do I always forget it's this simple when I need to do this task...  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, your new rectangle can be described as:

```
h = w / (16/9)
w = h * (16/9)
```

Your new rectangle should then be based on the width of the outer rectangle, so:

```
h = w0 / (16/9)
w = w0
```

Depending on how Lua works with numbers, you might want to make sure it is using real division as opposed to integer division - last time I looked was 2001, and my memory is deteriorating faster than coffee gets cold, but I seem to remember all numbers being floats anyway...

Comment: The problem is that the height of the outer rectangle might be more than the width, so that doesn't work.

Comment: yes it does, if you always want a wide aspect ratio. If not, well, check which is bigger, w0 or h0 and adjust the formula accordingly. That is what `if` statements are for ;)

Comment: This is only true if the rectangle is, say, 15:9.

Comment: Daren, simple if checking which one is bigger - for example, the shorter side of the outer rectangle can be shorter than 16/9 of the longer side, which will make the code fail.

Comment: OK. Sorry, me stupid, I just got it. So... That means, you either want to base the new rectangle on the height or the width, but your `if` statement shouldn't check which is larger, but instead compare the ratio.